# virtually isolate the network in the same AWS Cloud Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

I am new in the AWS Cloud services.
I assigned a project to prepare a new environment in the cloud, to which my team will later migrate their applications. The Stakeholders have come up with some Technical and Business requirements:

They are concerned about the security of the environment, so they have decided to virtually isolate their network from the rest of the customers and rest of the environments in the same AWS Cloud Account

Which AWS Cloud service I could try to use to implement this requirement?

Please let me know if I need to provide more details.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would question why the Stakeholders would assign someone with very little AWS experience the task of creating a secure network from scratch in it, and then reveal they are concerned about how secure it will be.  (Nothing personal against you, just seems like a strange approach)

Secondly, this is a deep topic, with multiple answers depending upon the specifics of your Technical and Business requirements...

From what I can gather, at a high level you're trying to implement a multi-VPC setup in a single AWS Account.

In short, there are too many scenarios to go into for a StackOverflow answer.  The best advice I could give would be to seek advice from an AWS networking/security architect (or consultant) if that is an option for you.  They should be able to review your requirements in detail and formulate an appropriate solution.

I'll give you an idea of the sorts of services/resources you should be looking to read up on if you want to implement a secure multi-VPC network in AWS:

- VPC peering connections or Transit Gateway to handle routing between VPCs
- NACLs to control layer 3 traffic into and out of your VPCs
- Security Groups to control layer 3 & 4 traffic into and out of the instances in your VPCs

Comment: Actually I am just doing the learning project . This is not the solution for a corporation. It is just for study. I will be more concrete next time. Thank you for your help, GreenyMcDuff.